# Create presence/absence variables from character string for long data

Tags: r, string, grepl

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
dat<- data.frame(ID= rep(c("A","B","C","D"),4),
             test= rep(c("pre","post"),8),
             item= c(rep("item1",8),rep("item2",8))
             answer= c("undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment", 
                       "graduateorprofessionalschool",
                       "undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "volunteeractivityoroutreach", 
                       "undergraduateeducation_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "employment",
                       "volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment", 
                       "graduateorprofessionalschool",
                       "undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "volunteeractivityoroutreach", 
                       "undergraduateeducation_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "employment",
                       "volunteeractivityoroutreach",
                       "undergraduateeducation_graduateorprofessionalschool_employment_volunteeractivityoroutreach"))
```

The `answer` column represents a "select all the apply" answer type- where the underscore separates selected answer options. For each `ID`, `test` and `item`, I would like to change this single variable to multiple presence/absence variables indicating the presence or absence of that answer component in the string. 1 indicates that answer option was present in the respondents answer and  0 represents that component was absent.  The variables `undergraduate`, `graduate`, `employment` and `volunteer` in `res` correspond to the following strings in `answer`, respectivley: `undergraduateeducation`, `graduateorprofessionalschool`,`employment`, `volunteeractivityoroutreach`. White spaces were removed.

The result data frame would look as follows:

```
res<- data.frame(ID= rep(c("A","B","C","D"),4),
             test= rep(c("pre","post"),8),
             item= c(rep("item1",8),rep("item2",8)),
             undergraduate= c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),
             graduate= c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
             employment=c(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
             volunteer=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```r
new_cols <- c('undergraduate', 'graduate', 'employment', 'volunteer')

cbind(dat[1:3],
      as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(dat$answer, "_"), 
      function(x) {
        z <- sapply(new_cols, function(y) as.numeric(grepl(paste0("\\b", y), x)))
        if(is.vector(z)) z else colSums(z)
      }))))
#>    ID test  item undergraduate graduate employment volunteer
#> 1   A  pre item1             1        1          1         0
#> 2   B post item1             0        1          0         0
#> 3   C  pre item1             1        1          1         1
#> 4   D post item1             0        0          0         1
#> 5   A  pre item1             1        0          1         1
#> 6   B post item1             0        0          1         0
#> 7   C  pre item1             0        0          0         1
#> 8   D post item1             1        1          1         1
#> 9   A  pre item2             1        1          1         0
#> 10  B post item2             0        1          0         0
#> 11  C  pre item2             1        1          1         1
#> 12  D post item2             0        0          0         1
#> 13  A  pre item2             1        0          1         1
#> 14  B post item2             0        0          1         0
#> 15  C  pre item2             0        0          0         1
#> 16  D post item2             1        1          1         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `tidyverse` to separate the data into rows on the `_`, then keep only the keywords (which will be used for column names). Then, we create a value column to note presence, then we can pivot to wide format, and fill the other values with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- dat %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(answer, sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(answer = str_extract(answer, "undergraduate|graduate|employment|volunteer"),
         value = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "answer", values_from = "value", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
   ID    test  item  undergraduate graduate employment volunteer
   <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A     pre   item1             1        1          1         0
 2 B     post  item1             0        1          0         0
 3 C     pre   item1             1        1          1         1
 4 D     post  item1             0        0          0         1
 5 A     pre   item1             1        0          1         1
 6 B     post  item1             0        0          1         0
 7 C     pre   item1             0        0          0         1
 8 D     post  item1             1        1          1         1
 9 A     pre   item2             1        1          1         0
10 B     post  item2             0        1          0         0
11 C     pre   item2             1        1          1         1
12 D     post  item2             0        0          0         1
13 A     pre   item2             1        0          1         1
14 B     post  item2             0        0          1         0
15 C     pre   item2             0        0          0         1
16 D     post  item2             1        1          1         1
```

*Test*

```
identical(result, as_tibble(res))

#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `group_by`?